# That-clause as an object after transitive verbs like "infer" and "inform"?

Tags: grammar

I came across an example sentence on [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/infer) of the word "infer", which is a transitive verb.

> He inferred that she was not interested in a relationship from what she said in her letter.

I wonder if the logic of this usage is to make the that-clause a direct object to "infer". If it's the case, can I also say something like:

> He informed that she would no longer attend the meetings.

instead of

> He informed **us** that she would no longer attend the meetings.

Comment: Some analyse the that-clause as a DO. The archetypal example is 'He said that he was tired.' However, different verbs have different affordances. Most would agree that 'He informed ...' cannot take a bare that-clause as DO. // See [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/58835/what-is-the-proper-use-of-informed-that).

Comment: Does this answer your first question? [Terminology: Definition of the term "direct object"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/439164/terminology-definition-of-the-term-direct-object)

Comment: No: that clauses cannot be direct objects. Leaving aside relative clauses, they are almost always **complement** to some verb, noun, adjective or preposition. In "He inferred [that she was not interested]" it is complement of "inferred". In "He informed us [that she would no longer attend the meetings]", "us" is Od of "informed" and the _that_ clause is second complement of "informed".

Comment: *Infer* is transitive. *Inform* is ditransitive. In "traditional" grammar terms, the *that*-clause functions as an object. The ditransitive *inform* needs two objects: *He informed [1] us [2] that she would no longer attend the meetings.* The transitive *infer* takes one object: *He inferred from what she said in her letter [1] that she was not interested in a relationship.*

Comment: @TinfoilHat Yes, but let's stick with 21c grammar, shall we. They stopped using leeches in the operating theatre many moons ago!