That clauses as direct objects

I find [verb] it [object] frustrating [object complement] that the liberals have gained fewer votes than last time" can also be written as:


I [subject] find [verb] {the fact} that the liberals have gained fewer votes than last time [object]frustrating [object complement].

My question:
Why do we need {the fact} to make 'that' clause as the object, when we have several sentences without that such as:

I believe that he is innocent.


He knew that something bad had happened.


I have edited the question. Thanks!

I'm not sure if it's a firm restriction, or if it's just clearer when using an object complement (especially with a long complex object) to use a few more words. (Obviously if there's no object complement, e.g. "I believe that he is innocent", the structure can be much simpler.) Why do you say we need "the fact" in this case? I can't find much in the way of examples either with or without "the fact".

According to you, is it ok if we omit 'the fact?'  I saw a question in another forum where the expert answers of different ways of writing this were: 1)I find {your failure in the exam} surprising. - correct
2) I find {the fact} {that you have failed the exam} surprising. - correct
3) {That you have failed the exam} I find surprising. correct
But
4) I find surprising {that you have failed the exam}. -wrong

I find it surprising {that you have failed the exam}.  -correct. I understand the others, but not the one in my question.


Here is a question regarding this subject from this forum: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/563145/that-clause-as-an-object-after-transitive-verbs-like-infer-and-inform I can't make much sense of the argument that "that clauses" cannot be objects. If they are not objects, what are they? One guy says they are complements. Verb complements are another term for direct objects, correct?

It's worth reading Jespersen on "content clauses"

It's not okay to omit "the fact" from your example. See my answer.

H&P's CGEL explains on page 963 why you cannot omit the fact from your example (Boldface mine.):

The content clause cannot itself  occupy the position between verb and predicative complement, for a clausal complement cannot in general be followed within the VP by another complement; however, a version  without the extrapositional it is possible if the content clause is preposed to prenuclear  position:  [27] i *I find t̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲h̲e̲ ̲t̲r̲i̲e̲d̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲r̲e̲t̲r̲a̲c̲t̲ ̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲s̲t̲a̲t̲e̲m̲e̲n̲t̲ hardly surprising.  ii T̲h̲a̲t̲ ̲h̲e̲ ̲t̲r̲i̲e̲d̲ ̲t̲o̲ ̲r̲e̲t̲r̲a̲c̲t̲ ̲h̲i̲s̲ ̲s̲t̲a̲t̲e̲m̲e̲n̲t̲ I find hardly surprising. A sample of complex-transitive verbs appearing in this construction

(Note * in CGEL means "ungrammatical".)
Your last two examples are different in that the clausal complement (that-clause) is not followed by another complement (e.g., frustrating).

Is the extraposition necessary for a sentence like "I like it when they visit here?" Here, we don't have a 'that clause", but we have a 'wh' clause and there is no object complement. Or is there any other reason for writing it with a dummy 'it?"

@A_Mendes I think that's a different construction altogether and should be posted as a separate question if need be.

Declarative content clauses (clauses that can stand on their own as sentences that make statements) in general are not allowed as objects in complex-transitive constructions (verbs with an object and an object-oriented predicative complement).

I find your early departure infuriating.
*I find that you left early infuriating.

Declarative content clauses must be extraposed - replaced by it and moved to the end of the clause.

I find it infuriating that you left early.

If you make the content clause a dependent in a noun phrase instead, then you no longer have a declarative content clause as object, but a noun phrase, so the extraposition is not required and in fact no longer possible.

I find the fact that you left early infuriating.
*I find it infuriating the fact that you left early.

The other sentences you proposed don't have a complex-transitive construction and so do not need a noun phrase in that position. They can have a declarative content clause or a noun phrase. However, if we make them complex-transitives, then we have to extrapose the object.

I believe that he is innocent.
*I believe that he is innocent possible.
I believe it possible that he is innocent.

Authoritative claims that the declarative content clauses must be extraposed can be found in most major modern grammars: The Cambridge Grammar of the English Langauge p963, 1408; A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language p1393; Oxford Modern English Grammar 11.3.2.2.

The comment section says not to say Thanks in comments. :)

<< I find it infuriating (the fact that you left early). >> is the afterthought explanatory appositive version, acceptable but belaboured.

Is the extraposition necessary for a sentence like "I like it when they visit here?" Here, we don't have a 'that clause", but we have a 'wh' clause and there is no object complement. Or is there any other reason for writing it with a dummy 'it?"

One problem is that without the fact that, your example is a garden path sentence. As readers proceed through a sentence that begins with I find that NP…, they are primed to interpret the that as introducing a subordinate clause, and to believe that everything after the that is a complete sentence of which the NP (noun phrase) is the subject, as in I find that the soup is too salty. (Unless of course it seems that the that is being used as a determiner, as in This soup is fine, but I find that soup too salty.) What they are unlikely to consider is the possibility that the sentence’s form will turn out to be the same as that of I find the soup too salty, where the that has been used to turn an entire subordinate clause into the object of find.


I find the fact that the liberals have gained fewer votes than last time frustrating.

The question asks why "the fact" is needed in this sentence. My answer would be that it's not essential, but it's certainly helpful in reading the sentence smoothly and accurately.
The OP parses the clause "that the liberals have gained fewer votes than last time" as an object. While I am not an expert in the terminology here, that's probably not the best practical way to look at the sentence. The key question is, what does the speaker find? Consider these sentences, both without the fact:

I find that the liberals have gained fewer votes than last time frustrating.
I find that the liberals have gained fewer votes than last time.

The first sentence read as a whole would probably be interpreted as meaning the same as the original. However, the second sentence shows the potential ambiguity. It has a neutral emotional sense; I read a report on the election and discovered this fact. By itself we have no idea whether you are frustrated, exhilarated or apathetic.
So even if we accept the grammar of sentence #1, the flow of the sentence makes it difficult to read correctly. We start off with I find that and assume that we are reading sentence #2. It's not till we get to the word "frustrating" that we realise there's more to the sentence.
So if we are committed to this overall word order, the addition of "the fact" helps us to read the sentence smoothly from the start. We instinctively know that there may be further relevant content at the other end of that fact.
The real "object" here is the emotion: "I find frustration in the fact that..."
Note also that the other examples from the OP that appear to be different, are not really different. Consider this:

I believe that he is innocent.

But this is not a parallel to sentence #1. It's a parallel to sentence #2. The better example would be:

I believe that he is innocent is absurd.

Again, this may technically be valid, but a better wording would be...

I believe it's absurd that he claims to be innocent.

or...

I believe his claim that he is innocent is absurd.


it's certainly helpful in reading the sentence smoothly and accurately. You nailed it.

Thanks Peter Kirkpatrick!

-1 because you answer "it's not essential" is wrong.
